# jdialog enter and escape not working

Tags: java, swing, escaping, key-bindings, enter

Context: I'm trying to create modal JDialog and pretty much replicate JOptionPane functionality with custom buttons with one condition - i don't want to use UIManager to set windows style.

Problem: JDialog doesn't answer to ESCAPE and ENTER keys like it's supposed to. I've tried all proposed solutions i could find online (multiple listeners solutions, setting default button etc.) and i can't get it to work.

Whole class is uploaded to pastebin at http://pastebin.com/Kcj82h2i

Actual key settings in extended JDialog class are done with

```
InputMap inputMap = getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap actionMap = getRootPane().getActionMap(); 

inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "returnyes");
actionMap.put("returnyes", new ResultYes());

inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "returnno");
actionMap.put("returnno", new ResultNo());
```

And the dialog gets called from JFrame with the following code:

```
if (results == 1)
{
    InvoiceLinesTableModel tm = (InvoiceLinesTableModel) tbl_invoiceItems.getModel();
    InvoiceLinesTableRow row = tm.getRow(tbl_invoiceItems.getSelectedRow());
    tm.deleteRow(row);
    tm.fireTableDataChanged();
    StaticFunctions.updateTableRowHeights(tbl_invoiceItems);
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `JDialog` is modal the call to `addCustomKeyMaps()` will be blocked when the window becomes visible. You should make this call *before* you call `setVisible(true)`.

Comment: @Reimus: answer accepted. I've been stuck with this problem for two days and i still can't believe how simple the solution is. **Thanks again**! Is it allowed to ask related question in the same thread or another question should be posted?

Comment: *" another question should be posted?"*  For later users who are searching for answers, that is generally better.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agreee. Too often I have seen questions practially re-written to _sqeeze-in_ another question making the original answer invalid.

Comment: Agreed.  That makes me cringe.  I would prefer to see both answers exist separately, with cross-links if appropriate.